# Jquery $.Ajax Freezes Browser

Tags: json, jquery

I have a function that makes a call that gets a Json Response and plots the data inside Google Plots... I do this function every 90 seconds so it updates my charts with the latest data....

This works great however whenever it is processing it seems to lock up the browser for a brief few seconds (even the loader freezes) I am okay if the graph part freezes but I do not want the Loader or other items to freeze I want the UI to still function while the graphs update.

Can someone help me maybe I should change the $.ajax

Here is the code:

```
function UpdateCharts() {
clearInterval(timerId);
BuildLineChart('power-chart', $('#datePower').val(), '1,28,32');
BuildLineChart('voltagecurrent-chart', currentDate, '13,15,17,5,7,9');
BuildLineChart('phasekw-chart', currentDate, '2,3,4');
BuildLineChart('phasevoltage-chart', currentDate, '13,15,17');
BuildLineChart('phasecurrent-chart', currentDate, '5,7,9,11');
timerId = setInterval(UpdateCharts, 90000);
}


// document ready function
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(UpdateCharts, 5000);
});
```

Build line chart then does this:

```
 function onDataReceived(seriesData) {
            var p = $.plot(placeholder, seriesData.seriesData, options);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Charts/LineChart?SeriesToGraph=' + dataPoints + '&DatePull=' + chartDate,
            method: 'GET',
            async: false,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
            $("." + placeHold + "-loader").html('<img src="/Assets/images/loaders/circular/066.gif" />');
            },
            complete: function() {
            $("." + placeHold + "-loader").html('');
            },
            success: onDataReceived
        });
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue with my ajax function freezing on the first run through.  I am using .get() and have tried with.ajac() and asynch true and still freezes the browser.  Occasionally I will get the browser error: a script is taking a long time to respond... yada yada.  Mine seems to then run on any further requests after the first one finishes loading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[async: false](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) causes the browser to wait for the request to complete before it moves on. Change it to async: true and it won't lock up the browser.

Comment: Is that the only thing in BuildLineChart? Because otherwise it definitely should not be blocking.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I just need async set to be false. Is it jQuery bug or something?

Comment: Great solution friend ;) (y)

Answer (score 5):

You have `async: false` set.  If you set it to `async: true`, then your AJAX request will happen asynchronously and *shouldn't* freeze your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried with

```
async: true
```

?

From  [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.